# What will be the minimum value of $\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What will be the minimum value of
$$\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ}$$ if 
$$p+q+r+s=5$$ where $p, q, r, s$ are positive reals?
I tried applying AM-GM inequality but it didn't help.

Comment: Those arguments are in degrees, no?

Comment: Yup degrees only.

Comment: It seems like you can do standard nonlinear optimization, like Lagrange multipliers, have you tried this?

Comment: $\frac{\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ}}{4} ≥ (p^2q^2r^2s^2)^\frac{1}{4}$   as  $\tan9^\circ.\tan81^\circ=1$  and $\tan27^\circ.\tan63^\circ=1$

$\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ} ≥4\sqrt{pqrs}$

Comment: ${\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ}}$

$={\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ}  + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ}} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ}$

$=2(ps+rs)$     as  $\tan9^\circ.\tan81^\circ=1$  and $\tan27^\circ.\tan63^\circ=1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ) \left ( \frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ} \right ) \geq  {(p+q+r+s)}^2=5^2$

From Cauchy–Schwarz

Hence
$$\frac{p^2}{\tan9^\circ} + \frac{q^2}{\tan27^\circ} + \frac{r^2}{\tan63^\circ} + \frac{s^2}{\tan81^\circ} \, \, \, \,\geq \frac{  5^2 }{\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ }$$
Then take $$p = \frac{ 5 \tan9^\circ}{\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ}$$
$$q = \frac{ 5 \tan27^\circ}{\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ}$$
$$r = \frac{ 5 \tan63^\circ}{\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ}$$
$$s = \frac{ 5 \tan81^\circ}{\tan9^\circ+\tan27^\circ+\tan63^\circ+\tan81^\circ}$$
And sum up.
Note that those $ \tan  $ are positive

Comment: @TheApe glad I could help.

Comment: How did you find those values of p, q r and s? I understood upto the inequality statement.

Comment: @Rick The inequality is not enough to find the minimum of the expression, as the lower bound may not be attained for $p,q,r,s$ as described. So first we find the values such that the lower bounded is attained by knowing when C-S achieves its minimum. The C-S inequality $$(\sum_i a_i^2)(\sum_i b_i^2)\geq (\sum_i a_ib_i)^2$$ achieves its minimum when $a_i=\lambda b_i$ for some $\lambda. $ The latter justifies the choice for $p,q,r,s$. We chose $\lambda$ so that the sum of $p,q,r,s$ is $5$.